# Adding subview with constraints makes view black

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a overlay over for all my viewcontrollers by adding this code to my "BaseViewController". However it result in all ViewControllers turning black and behaving oddly.

```
override public func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    overlayView = UIView()
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //For testing
    view.addSubviewWithMatchingConstraints(overlayView)
    ...
}
```

And in UIView extension:

```
func addSubviewWithMatchingConstraints(subView: UIView)
{
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(subView)

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the parent rather than the child.

```
childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

fixed it